# Looping through order records and concatenating duplicate values into strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through an array of records in javascript (airtable scripting block).

[image]

I need to loop through the array and concatenate all **Order_Num's**  that are for the same SKU. For example:-

[image]

I'm really struggling with the logic and getting it to work. I'd appreciate any guidance or help please.

Here's what I've tried so far:-

```
let table = base.getTable("Daily Orders");
let view = table.getView("Unfulfilled Daily Orders");
let sku = table.getField("Line Items: Sku"); 
let ordernum = table.getField("Order: Name"); 
let currsku = "";
let ordstr = "";


let result = await view.selectRecordsAsync({
    sorts: [{field: "Line Items: Variant Id", direction: "asc"}]
});

for (let record of result.records) {


    ordernum = record.getCellValue("Order: Name");
    ordstr = ordernum;
    if (record.getCellValue(sku)[0] == currsku) {
        ordstr = ordstr + ordernum;
        output.text(ordstr);
        output.text(ordernum);
    } else {
        ordernum ="";
    }

     currsku = record.getCellValue(sku)[0]; 

 }
```

Array structure from result.

```
(7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#3439"
SKU: "AlexSaleBeanieAdultCharcoal"
1: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#999903"
SKU: "AlexSaleBeanieAdultCharcoal"
2: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#3479"
SKU: "CocoBeanieKidsCharcoal48yrs"
3: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#3477"
SKU: "CocobearBeanieBabyMistShell612mth"
4: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#999901"
SKU: "CocobearBeanieBabyMistShell612mth"
5: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#999902"
SKU: "CocobearBeanieBabyMistShell612mth"
6: Object
fields: Object
Order_num: "#3478"
SKU: "CocobearBeanieBabySand03mth"
```

[image]
Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Could you please add the structure of the arrays ? Also please let us know what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I've added what I've tried so far. Does this help? It's more about the logic that I'm trying to figure out. The array structure is just 2 colums order_num, and sku like in the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple solution using .find and .forEach  methods

```js
var arr = [
 
{fields: {Order_Num: "#3439", SKU:"AlexSaleBeanieAdultCharcoal"}},
{fields: {Order_Num: "#999903", SKU:"AlexSaleBeanieAdultCharcoal"}},
{fields: {Order_Num: "#3477", SKU:"CocobearBeanieBabyMistShell612mth"}},
{fields: {Order_Num: "#999901", SKU:"CocobearBeanieBabyMistShell612mth"}},
{fields: {Order_Num: "#999902", SKU:"CocobearBeanieBabyMistShell612mth"}},
{fields: {Order_Num: "#3479", SKU:"CocoBeanieKidsCharcoal48yrs"}},
{fields: {Order_Num: "#3478", SKU:"CocobearBeanieBabySand03mth"}}

]

var res = [];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  var found = res.find(ob => ob.fields.SKU === obj.fields.SKU);
  if(found){
    var order_nums = found.fields.Order_Num;
    var new_order_num = order_nums+","+obj.fields.Order_Num;
    found.fields.Order_Num = new_order_num;
  } else {
      res.push({fields: {SKU: obj.fields.SKU,Order_Num:obj.fields.Order_Num}});
  }  
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works in isolation, I need to adapt it to my environment which is difficult because the array structure is very different - it's within an airtable scripting block. See new array structure in my question.

Comment: I think any answer has to work in a loop and not the array object itself as a whole because of the unusual structure that seems to use record pointers

Comment: I saw the structure , there are no SKU s , on what basis will you then group the order_nums ?

Comment: Can you get your code to work on this array structure please - see new array structure in question

Comment: yes I believe so -will post an image in the question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219881/discussion-between-jonathan-lyon-and-harmandeep-singh-kalsi).

Comment: Hi Harmandeep, can you please adjust it so I just have an array of the concatenated Order_Num's  without the SKU field please?

Comment: My question is on what basis you will group the Order_Num ? Or may you can do one thing , one you have got the res array , just map through it and get the Order_Num only.